# Maven coordinates for vert.x?

Tags: java, maven, vert.x

I am trying to add vert.x in a maven project, but it seems like it is not in the central repository. Am I wrong?

If it is available from Maven, what are the dependency coordinates? Thanks.

Comment: I have found the following: http://groups.google.com/group/vertx/browse_thread/thread/87a0fd7dd7318a36, but these artifacts are not available yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We haven't uploaded vert.x into Maven Central yet, but it is near the top of the TODO list.

I'll update this post when it's done.

[UPDATE]

The next release is imminent and will feature a Gradle-based build and Mavenised modular components, amongst other things.

The Maven co-ordinates will be: "org.vert-x:vertx-%stuff%:%version%".

(Note the dash: The project doesn't currently own the org.vertx domain, so Maven wouldn't let us use it.)

[UPDATE2]

vert.x 1.2.1.final was released into Maven Central, with coordinates as above.

In Gradle for example:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.vert-x:vertx-core:1.2.1.final"
  compile "org.vert-x:vertx-platform:1.2.1.final"
}
```

See http://github.com/vert-x for examples of how we're using Gradle to build modules.

Comment: I'm looking forward to this as well thanks Pidster.  I've been playing around with it and it'd even easier for people to try it with a simple groovy script that can use a grape `@Grab` annotation to install vert.x-core (and have the other dependencies, `vert.x-platform`, `netty` and possibly the jackson jars come down automatically.  When you do upload it, please post the explicit maven strings needed to get it to resolve, I don't know how often I've seen projects that just say "it's in maven central" without making this explicit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If there are no vert.x artifacts in public Maven repos you can distribute the library with your project using a local (project based) repo using:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-project-repo</id>
        <url>file:${basedir}/lib/repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After that, you only need to recreate a Maven repo structure (groupId, artifactId, version) in /lib/repository.

This approach will prevents you the need to install the vert.x dependency in each environment you want to compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see a "pom.xml" file in the vert.x source code rep, or a Maven artifact in Maven Central, so I think you are out of luck ... for now.

You could always download the vert.x sources, do a local build, slap together a minimal POM file (with your own invented group/id/version) and install it into your local repo.  That will tide you over until the developers complete the Maven-ization and publication.